# Linux: Sample programs to load CPU, Memory and Hard disk

Tags: linux, memory, cpu

I am doing a perform analysis on various Linux distributions. I want to measure the performance of Linux distributions in the below scenarios

1) High CPU utilization

2) High Memory utilization

3) High IO utilization

4) High CPU IO wait

I want to write C programs in order to achieve each of the scenarios, so that I can
run those programs individually or in combination to measure the performance. 
I wrote some sample c programs to load CPU , but I need c programs to handle the other scenarios. 
Any programming help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing a perform analysis on various Linux distributions.

Unless you are very careful about what you are doing, you are unlikely to find the subtle performance differences between kernel versions and distributions in a meaningful way. From the level of just running programs, there is fairly little difference between distributions, except which Linux kernel version they use.

> 2) High Memory utilization

Your program needs to malloc() a bunch of memory - and then write to it. Some Linux distributions by default [overcommit memory](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/001nov04/features/vm/). Simply calling malloc() to create an array and writing to each element should be sufficient.

> 3) High IO utilization

Consider using [fio](http://freecode.com/projects/fio) instead of writing your own code here. If you do need to write your own code, then you'll need to decide a couple of things:

1. Random or sequential IO? It's less important with SSDs, but on magnetic drives the two cases have very different performance characteristics.
2. Reads or writes? Different storage subsystems may perform very differently with reads and writes.
3. Direct IO or buffered IO? Are you wanting to stress the whole end-to-end IO subsystem, or just the underlying storage. Flags like O_DIRECT and O_SYNC substantially change the way the kernel handles IO.
4. File system IO or block IO? Are you interested in testing the filesystem's performance with creating and deleting files, or just doing IO to a block file?

The simplest code you can write here just uses open() to create a large file, then uses rand() together with pread() and pwrite() to do random block IO in that file. If you want to test the filesystem, you need to call open() and unlink() a bunch of times.

IO benchmarking is a very subtle topic, which is why I would encourage you to stick with a well-understood tool like [fio](http://freecode.com/projects/fio).

> 4) High CPU IO wait

Combining your IO loader with your CPU loader should lead to high IO wait. If you're stressing any IO subsystem, you'll get IO wait.